# Datediff for date and hour (24 hours)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know it's a simple question, but I'm stuck. I tried `DateDiff` day and hour seperately but I want my date can detect my time if its over 24 hours.

For example:

```
Date1: 20/12/2011
Time1: 9:00

Date2: 21/12/2011
Time2 : 13:00

Days Taken: 1
Time Taken: 28
```

I want to calculate the days and hours, so 1 day and 4 hours is my desired result.

Can anyone please help me how to do with this? Appreciate.

Comment: All these answers assume your type is `DATETIME` but your question looks if you might have `DATE` and `TIME` stored seperately as you can do from `SQL Server 2008` onwards. Could you clarify?

Comment: @MarkD ya, my data type is DATETIME and my date and time is store seperately. Can you give some advise? Thanks

Comment: Sure I can - but I would first need to know whats wrong with the provided answers?

Comment: @MarkD I get coversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps with the help of [`MODULO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx):

```
SELECT (
  DATEDIFF(dd,
    CONVERT(datetime,'20/12/2011 09:00:00',104),
    CONVERT(datetime,'21/12/2011 13:00:00',104))
 ) AS [days taken],
(
  DATEDIFF(hh,
    CONVERT(datetime,'20/12/2011 09:00:00',104),
    CONVERT(datetime,'21/12/2011 13:00:00',104))
   % 24
 ) AS [hours taken]
```

Result:

```
DAYS TAKEN      HOURS TAKEN
    1                4
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1910/0)

Answer (score 2):

In sql-server;

```
declare @d1 datetime = '20111220 09:00:00'
declare @d2 datetime = '20111221 13:00:00'

select hours/24 daysTaken, hours%24 hoursTaken
from (
    select datediff(hh,@d1,@d2) hours
) A

--Results
daysTaken hoursTaken
   1          4
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server

```
Select datediff(hour,date1,date2)/24.0 from table
```

Comment: This will result in the hours being displayed as a fraction of days.